# Compare two strings by meaning using LLMs

Tags: python, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, large-language-model

I'd like to use some of the good large language models to estimate how similar the **meanings** of two strings are, for example "cat" and "someone who likes to play with yarn", or "cat" and "car".

Maybe some libraries provide a function for comparing strings, or we could implement some method such as measuring the similarity of their embeddings in a deep layer or whatever is appropriate.

I hope that something without much boilerplate code is possible. Something like:

```py
import language_models, math
my_llm = language_models.load('llama2')
print(math.dist(
    my_llm.embedding('cat'),
    my_llm.embedding('someone who likes to play with yarn')))
```

Ideally, it should be easy to try different recent LLMs. (In the "example" above, that would mean replacing `'llama2'` by another model name.)

Comment: I would go with `summarization with llm` + `lemmatization`

Answer (score 1):

Spacy is the way:

```
import spacy

# Load the language model
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

# Example sentences
sentence1 = "I love coding "
sentence2 = "I love studying"

# Process the sentences using spaCy
doc1 = nlp(sentence1)
doc2 = nlp(sentence2)

# Compute the similarity between the two sentences
similarity = doc1.similarity(doc2)

print(f"Similarity between the two sentences: {similarity}")
```

Output:

```
Similarity between the two sentences: 0.8791585322649781
```

The similarity value will be a number between `0` and `1`, where `1` means the sentences are exactly the same, and `0` means they have no similarity. This value can give you an idea of how similar the meanings of the two sentences are.

Comment: The documentation says [here](https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#similarity-expectations): << The similarity of Doc and Span objects defaults to the average of the token vectors. This means that the vector for “fast food” is the average of the vectors for “fast” and “food”, which isn’t necessarily representative of the phrase “fast food”. >>. However, I want the phrase `'someone who likes to play with yarn'` to be semantically understood.

Comment: @root `This value can give you an idea of how similar the meanings of the two sentences are`

Comment: "Two documents expressing the same meaning with dissimilar wording will return a lower similarity score than two documents that happen to contain the same words while expressing different meanings." My question is about the meaning of text.

Comment: Can spaCy compute embeddings of entire phrases? Maybe we could compare them directly, without using spaCy's `similarity()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Though it lacks some of the latest models, you could give Hugging Face's [sentence-transformers](https://www.sbert.net/) package a try. The models it provides are all specifically trained for embedding comparison.

> SentenceTransformers is a Python framework for state-of-the-art
> sentence, text and image embeddings.
>
> You can use this framework to compute sentence / text embeddings for
> more than 100 languages. These embeddings can then be compared e.g.
> with cosine-similarity to find sentences with a similar meaning. This
> can be useful for **semantic textual similarity**, semantic search, or
> paraphrase mining.

The underlying model is easy to switch out, and HuggingFace provides [a few thousands options to pick from](https://huggingface.co/models?library=sentence-transformers).

```py
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer, util

model = SentenceTransformer("all-distilroberta-v1")

query_embedding = model.encode("cat")
passage_embedding = model.encode(["car", "someone who likes to play with yarn"])

# Results aren't great with the all-distilroberta-v1 model
print("Similarity:", util.cos_sim(query_embedding, passage_embedding))
```